# Most efficient way to compare words in list / dict in Python

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have the following sentence and dict :

```
sentence = "I love Obama and David Card, two great people. I live in a boat"

dico = {
'dict1':['is','the','boat','tree'],
'dict2':['apple','blue','red'],
'dict3':['why','Obama','Card','two'],
}
```

I want to match the number of the elements that are in the sentence and in a given dict. The heavier method consists in doing the following procedure:

```
classe_sentence = []
text_splited = sentence.split(" ")
dic_keys = dico.keys()
for key_dics in dic_keys:
    for values in dico[key_dics]:
        if values in text_splited:
            classe_sentence.append(key_dics)

from collections import Counter
Counter(classe_sentence)
```

Which gives the following output:

```
Counter({'dict1': 1, 'dict3': 2})
```

However it's not efficient at all since there are two loops and it is raw comparaison. I was wondering if there is a faster way to do that. Maybe using `itertools` object. Any idea ?

Thanks in advance !

Comment: Your `dico'  data structure does not need to be a dictionary, if it needs to be a sequence.

Comment: @jsbueno: Not if you want to give each sequence a label. Those labels are used in the output here.

Comment: @jsbueno What do you mean ? Will-it increase the speed of the process ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the  `set` data data type for all you comparisons, and the  `set.intersection` method to get the number of matches.

It will increare algorithm efficiency, but it will only count each word once, even if it shows up in several places in the sentence.

```
sentence = set("I love Obama and David Card, two great people. I live in a boat".split())

dico = {
'dict1':{'is','the','boat','tree'},
'dict2':{'apple','blue','red'},
'dict3':{'why','Obama','Card','two'}
}


results = {}
for key, words in dico.items():
    results[key] = len(words.intersection(sentence))
```

Comment: this can be combined with a Counter, first make a counter and a set from the given sentence and then sum the count of every member in the intersection

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want case-sensitive matching:

```
from collections import defaultdict
sentence_words = defaultdict(lambda: 0)
for word in sentence.split(' '):
    # strip off any trailing or leading punctuation
    word = word.strip('\'";.,!?')
    sentence_words[word] += 1
for name, words in dico.items():
    count = 0
    for x in words:
        count += sentence_words.get(x, 0)
    print('Dictionary [%s] has [%d] matches!' % (name, count,))
```